# Uploading Trigger.IO package fails with ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Code Signing..." for Forge app

Tags: trigger.io

Toolkit/Forge 2.1.0. Packaging with App store provisioning profile. `forge package ios --profile DISTRIBUTION`

`config.json` contains:

```
"DISTRIBUTION": {
    "provisioning_profile": "/Users/marty/divination/Breath_of_the_Horse_Store.mobileprovision",
    "developer_certificate_path": "/Users/marty/divination/ios_distribution.cer"
}
```

Fails with:

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/device-ios.app/Forge' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I notice sometimes forge retains old config.json info. We did changed to different apple account to generate new provisioning profile and certificates. Is there a `forge clean`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem resided in switching to provisioning profile and certificate from a different Apple developer account. The new certificate was not originated on my machine and thus no key was available.

The real solution is to be setup part of the team for that apple account, but for a shorter term fix, I generated a new CSR from my machine that was used to create the certificate on the other Apple account.